# JAVA ArrayList Class call to another Class

Tags: java, arraylist, call

I am a beginner at this, so excuse my simple question.

I have a Diary Program with 2 Classes, Diary and Job.

Diary is the main class and from it I need to call Job to do the work.

Below are the codes of both classes. Class Job works fine by itself, it is class Diary that I have problem to call class Job to do the work and return.

Class Job add 3 fields.

How can I call Job from Diary and return back with results stored in the ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Diary {
     ArrayList<Job> jobs;
     String jobName, jobDay, jobPriority;


    public Diary() {
       jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    }
}

public class Job {

    public Job(String jobName, String jobDay, String jobPriority) {
        name = jobName;
        day = jobDay;
        priority = jobPriority;
    }

    /**
     * return the varaibles
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    // print the job details
    public String getJob() {
        return name + " on a " + day + " this week and its priority is " + priority;
    }
}
```

Thanks to the guys who helped in solving it.

My followup question is that I tried printed the content of the ArrayList but with no success. I used the following but they keep giving me the address of the memory location instead of the content. I used things like these but nothing seems to work.

```
public void addJob(String jobName, String jobDay, String jobPriority)
{
 System.out.println( Arrays.toString(jobs)); 
 System.out.println(jobs.get(0));
 System.out.println(jobs.toString().replaceAll("\[\]", ""));         
 System.out.println(jobs.toString(jobs));
 System.out.println(""+jobs.get(0).jobName);
}
```

Any idea.

Comment: Do you create an instance of Job? You have to have an instance of it if you want to call methods on it?

Comment: `Job job = new Job(name, day, priority);`, then you can add it to the ArrayList.

Comment: You need code the orchestrate your objects. Code the create jobs and add them to the list - btw. the var name onejob for an array list is confusing.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said but still the Job class does not get activated and I don't see its input boxes, while if I run the Job class alone I can see them.

Comment: Side note: you are defining a new variable in your Diary::Diary() instead of assigning the existing instance variable

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two lists of jobs - one for the entire object, and one just in the constructor. Also, let's rename your list:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Diary {

    ArrayList<Job> jobs;

    public Diary() {
        jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
    }
}
```

Now, somewhere you need to add some jobs to the list:

```
public Diary() {
    jobs = new ArrayList<Job>();

    jobs.add(new Job("Do something", "Monday", "HIGH"));
    jobs.add(new Job("Do something else", "Tuesday", "MED"));
}
```

Then, you probably want to list the jobs:

```
public class Diary {

    ...

    public void printJobs {
        for(Job job : jobs) {
            System.out.println(job.getJob());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, I will try your solution.

Comment: Hi again, I tried printed the content of the ArrayList but with no success. I used the following but they keep giving me the address of the memory location instead of the content. I used things like these but nothing seems to work.  //System.out.println( Arrays.toString(jobs));
        System.out.println(jobs.get(0));
        System.out.println(jobs.toString().replaceAll("\\[\\]", ""));
        //System.out.println(jobs.toString(jobs));
        //System.out.println(""+jobs.get(0).jobName);

Comment: You already wrote a method to get a string description of the job. It's called getJob(). I used that to print the details (see the last code section of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Job> jobs= new ArrayList<Job>()
```

isn't doing anything and the name onejob is confusing. I recommend jobs instead.

Create the job, then add it to the arraylist jobsyou made already.

```
Job job  = new Job(someName, someDay, somePriority);
jobs.add(job);
```

Comment: thanks danny, that was helpful, it working now and I am trying to print the whole array content, see if I can do it.

Comment: Hi Danny, Need help again, can you please look at the updated question about printing the arrayList and help out if you can. thanks.

Comment: Added a new answer due to space limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing you have to remember is that an Arraylist is an object and so are it's entries, so you can't just toString those objects unless they have an toString method override.

Assuming you are calling addJob from inside diary, you're not actually doing anything with the info you're passing.  You need to create a job and add it to your arraylist.

```
public void addJob(String jobName, String jobDay, String jobPriority) {
    Job job = new Job(jobName, jobDay, jobPriority);
    jobs.add(job);
}
```

Then I would create a new method to get all the jobs and list them, using the getJob method that you already created insode of your job class.

```
public void listJobs(){
    for(job : jobs) {
        System.out.println(job.getJob());
    }
}
```

Make sense?